# How to do product sorting when we search for certain product in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-filter

views.py:-

```
def search(request):
global pro
global products
if not request.GET.get('price_filter') == '1' or request.GET.get('price_filter') == '2':
    q = request.GET.get("q")
    products = Product.objects.filter(active=True, name__icontains=q)
    categories = Category.objects.filter(active=True)
    brands = Brand.objects.filter(active=True)
    context = {"products": products,
               "categories": categories,
                "brands": brands,
                "title": q + " - search"}
    return render(request, "shop/home.html", context)
pro = products

if request.GET.get('price_filter') == '1':
    products = pro.order_by('price')
    categories = Category.objects.filter(active=True)
    brands = Brand.objects.filter(active=True)
    context = {"products": products,
               "categories": categories,
               "brands": brands}
    return render(request, "shop/home.html", context)

elif request.GET.get('price_filter') == '2':
    products = pro.order_by('-price')
    categories = Category.objects.filter(active=True)
    brands = Brand.objects.filter(active=True)
    context = {"products": products,
               "categories": categories,
               "brands": brands}
    return render(request, "shop/home.html", context)
```

In HTML:-

```
<form method='get' action='#' style="margin-top:-20px; margin-left: 8px;">
        <input class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="checkbox" value="1" name="price_filter"/>Low to High

        <input class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="checkbox" value="2" name="price_filter"/>High to Low
        <button class="btn" type="submit" value="Sort">Sort</button>
    </form>
```

Using that search we I am able to sort low to high, but when I choose High to Low, it shows certain **Error**:-

```
Cannot use None as a query value
```

**I know this is not the right method to do this, but can please help me out with this, or guide me with the correct way to do sorting.**

Comment: try to print `q`.

Comment: print `pro` in your last block of elif which has condition `==2` it get any value let me know

Comment: @l.b.vasoya It's showing none, it's not getting any value.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occuring for this line:

```
if not request.GET.get('price_filter') == '1' or request.GET.get('price_filter') == '2':
                                                ^^^
```

It states that if there is no value of `request.GET.get('price_filter')` and there is value of `request.GET.get('price_filter')`. I think here it should be a **not** clause like this:

```
if not request.GET.get('price_filter') == '1' or not request.GET.get('price_filter') == '2':
                                                 ^^^
```

Reason is that, there is not input field for q in your template.

Also, you can store the querystring values in variables to make this code bit cleaner:

```
price_filter = request.GET.get('price_filter')

if price_filter not in ["1", "2"]:
    q = request.GET.get("q")
    # rest of the code
elif price_filter == "1":
    # more code
elif price_filter == "2":
    # more code
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try code as i give

```
def search(request):
    price_filter = request.GET.get('price_filter',None) 
    context = {}
    if price_filter not in '12': 
        q = request.GET.get("q")
        products = Product.objects.filter(active=True, name__icontains=q)
        context = {"title": q + " - search"}

    if price_filter == '1':
        pro = Product.objects.filter(active=True, name__icontains=q) if request.GET.get("q",None) else  Product.objects.filter(active=True)
        products = pro.order_by('price')

    elif price_filter == '2':
        pro = Product.objects.filter(active=True, name__icontains=q) if request.GET.get("q",None) else  Product.objects.filter(active=True)
        products = pro.order_by('-price')



    categories = Category.objects.filter(active=True)
    brands = Brand.objects.filter(active=True)               
    context =context.update({"products": products,
                   "categories": categories,
                    "brands": brands})               
    return render(request, "shop/home.html", context)
```

If any problem face or work this stuff then let me know

Answer (score 0):

In views I changed this and it is working completely fine now:-

views.py

```
def search(request):
global pro
global products
if request.GET.get('price_filter') not in ["1", "2"]:
    q = request.GET.get("q")
    products = Product.objects.filter(active=True, name__icontains=q)
    categories = Category.objects.filter(active=True)
    brands = Brand.objects.filter(active=True)
    context = {"products": products,
               "categories": categories,
                "brands": brands,
                "title": q + " - search"}
    return render(request, "shop/home.html", context)
pro = products

if request.GET.get('price_filter') == '1':
    products = pro.order_by('price')
    categories = Category.objects.filter(active=True)
    brands = Brand.objects.filter(active=True)
    context = {"products": products,
               "categories": categories,
               "brands": brands}
    return render(request, "shop/home.html", context)

elif request.GET.get('price_filter') == '2':
    products = pro.order_by('-price')
    categories = Category.objects.filter(active=True)
    brands = Brand.objects.filter(active=True)
    context = {"products": products,
               "categories": categories,
               "brands": brands}
    return render(request, "shop/home.html", context)
```